# What's the formal definition of a ceramic in chemistry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, materials, ceramics

Dictionary.com defines a ceramic as:

> noun (used with a singular verb) the art or technology of making
> objects of clay and similar materials treated by firing. (used with a
> plural verb) articles of earthenware, porcelain, etc.

This definition seems very narrow. There are numerous types of materials including aluminum oxide, uranium oxide and a variety of super conductors that are also classified as ceramics by chemists. What is the formal definition of a ceramic in the field of chemistry? Would teeth, for instance, fit under that definition of a ceramic?

Comment: Teeth are usually not put in ovens nor furnaces. Also, it may be a composite structure with proteins like mollusk shells.

Comment: I don't think the dictionary definition is very useful here. Chemists would mostly describe teeth as a ceramic and might even be inspired by nature to help design better ceramics. The dictionary is biased towards how most ceramics are *made* not what they are.

Comment: The enamel on the outside would be a ceramic material -- but inside teeth is organic matter.

Comment: To answer the question;
"Do teeth fit the definition of a ceramic material?" Let's look at the question again, it speaks of "a" material. Since teeth are mosty made up of a bone-like material called 'Keratine' (if i'm correct, hair and nails are as well.) And only the outer, protective layer is made of a ceramic-like material. I would say that they most likely do NOT fit that definition. ...but i could be wrong.

Comment: As they speak about thermally processed manmade material, I do not see how teeth could fit.

Answer (score 2):

A keramics is an opaque substance made from different amounts of different oxides in non stoichiometric amounts and homogenized by heating to a high temperature. The temperature must be high enough to produce finally a compact solid, even if no melting points are really achieved.
The definition of keramics has recently been extended and includes mixtures containing organic substances or polymers that do not require a high temperature for the compact solid to be created.